# WooCommerce Multisite -- importing products IN subsites FROM main site

Tags: multisite, woocommerce-offtopic

I have [WooCommerce Catalog Mode by XAdapter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/prices-by-user-role/) installed which hides pricing on the main site from guests. But what I need to do is going to require a custom plugin, to customize cart functionality on the main site only. I just need some direction as to how to achieve this, i.e., cart/checkout conversion to product selection to import.

1. Products including variable products need to be able to be added to the cart.
2. Checkout needs to forego purchase functionality and import products in cart.
3. Inventory with all subsite products that are on main site need be displayed on a separate page and excluded from regular Catalog.

I also have [WooCommerce Multistore](https://woomultistore.com/) installed, which allows for the main site admin to push/distribute products among subsites, but not the other way around. I was thinking to somehow hook into that plugin to utilize its existing functionality.